# DataTable to .accdb database

Tags: asp.net, excel, ms-access, datatable, oledb

I am populating a DataSet with data from an excel sheet. I now need to insert this data into a table in an Access database that has identical structure.

Convention would dictate that I iterate over the rows of the DataTable and make an INSERT query for each, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to accomplish this? Perhaps something analogous to SqlBulkCopy for SQL Server?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(path) & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
    Dim adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE EmpID IS NOT NULL", connection)
    Dim results = New System.Data.DataSet
    connection.Open()
    adapter.Fill(results)
    connection.Close()
    connection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Leaves.accdb"))
    `Now, short of a loop, how can I insert results.Tables(0) into my database?
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can copy straight from an Excel table to an Access table. I suggest you do that.

Comment: @Remou How would I go about doing this? (Note that I cannot use Interop for various reasons.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADO, for example:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( ADate ) 
SELECT SomeDate FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$a1:a4]
```

Where the connection is to the Access database. If you wish to use the whole sheet, refer to [Sheet1$] as your table, if you wish to use a named range, just refer to it by name.